# What's this decorator syntax before constructor argument for in typescript?

Tags: typescript, decorator

What's the differences between `constructor( @IStorageService storageService: IStorageService)`  and   `constructor( storageService: IStorageService)` ?

code from [vscode first commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/8f35cc47683#diff-bb59cf53a554a6aadee0bd5aa7cdf3252b54b29069b2704f8abc01cab3e1ac12) on github

```js
import {TPromise} from 'vs/base/common/winjs.base';
import {Remotable, IThreadService} from 'vs/platform/thread/common/thread';
import {IStorageService, StorageScope} from 'vs/platform/storage/common/storage';

@Remotable.MainContext('MainThreadStorage')
export class MainThreadStorage {

    private _storageService: IStorageService;

    constructor( @IStorageService storageService: IStorageService) {
        this._storageService = storageService;
    }
```

I have never seen code using decorator syntax in this way ( before constructor's argument ), and I couldn't find [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators) mentioning this usage.

Comment: Angular uses [decorators on parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) so that it can do dependency injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter decorators are documented at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators

> A Parameter Decorator is declared just before a parameter declaration. The parameter decorator is applied to the function for a class constructor or method declaration. A parameter decorator cannot be used in a declaration file, an overload, or in any other ambient context (such as in a declare class).
>
> The expression for the parameter decorator will be called as a function at runtime, with the following three arguments:
>
> - Either the constructor function of the class for a static member, or the prototype of the class for an instance member.
> - The name of the member.
> - The ordinal index of the parameter in the function’s parameter list.